# Merge duplicate records into one while doing approximate deduplication

Tags: python, duplicates

I have some product names in which there are some duplicates due to some misspellings, noisy words etc. I am using probabilistic LSH algorithm to identify the potential duplicates for each name and then find the exact ones using Jaro-Winkler distance by defining a certain minimum threshold distance for pair of names to be marked as a duplicate as the number of distance calculation operation otherwise would be very large since the name are in millions.

The problem is to merge the identified duplicate records into one. Now since I am using a probabilistic LSH algorithm to identify the potential duplicates and the find the exact ones using a high threshold on Jaro-Winkler distance it is possible that a case like below may occur:

```
name, duplicates
aa battery, [aa battry, aa batteries]
aa battry, [aa batteries, aa bettery]
```

where duplicate field refer to the names identified as duplicates. Now I need to create single list which doesn't have any duplicates.

Also, one other problem I am facing is to figure which one is the correct name among all the identified duplicates. For now i am using nltk english words corpus and select the name with most proper english words. In case of clash, I select the name with the longest length to be correct. Any suggestions around this are also welcome.

Comment: The second line contains `bettery` with a `e` instead of a `a`. Is it or not a typo? And what is the expected result here?

Comment: yes, the duplicates are mostly due to typos only. The expectation is to map all these a single name and say others are just duplicates of that. Identifying that single name is itself another problem statement as mentioned in the last para of 
 the question